# Combinatorical integral

Tags: integration, combinatorics, permutations

For a physics problem (in three spatial dimensions) I need to generalise the following identity.
\begin{align}\oint_{r=1} \prod_{j=1}^{2l}\hat{r}^{i_j} d\Omega= \beta_l \underbrace{\left[\delta^{i_1i_2}\delta^{i_3}\delta^{i_4}\cdots \delta^{2l-1}\delta^{2l}+\cdots \right]}_{\frac{(2l)!}{2^{l}l!} \text{permutations of } i \text{'s}} && l\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}\end{align}
Does anybody know the general form of $\beta_l$? I have already determined a few terms:
$\beta_0 = 4\pi, \beta_1 = \frac{4\pi}{3},\beta_2 = \frac{4\pi}{15}, \beta_3 = \frac{4\pi}{105}$. This leads to identities such as,
\begin{align}
    \oint_{r=1} \hat{r}^i\hat{r}^j\hat{r}^k\hat{r}^l\hat{r}^m\hat{r}^n d\Omega = \frac{4\pi}{105} \Big(&\delta^{ij}\delta^{kl}\delta^{mn} + \delta^{ij} \delta^{km}\delta^{ln}+\delta^{ij}\delta^{kn}\delta^{lm}\\
    +& \delta^{ik}\delta^{jl}\delta^{mn} +\delta^{ik}\delta^{jm}\delta^{ln} +\delta^{ik}\delta^{jn}\delta^{lm} \\
    +&\delta^{il}\delta^{jk}\delta^{mn} + 
    \delta^{il}\delta^{jm}\delta^{kn} + 
    \delta^{il}\delta^{jn}\delta^{km} \\
    +& \delta^{im}\delta^{jk}\delta^{ln} + \delta^{im}\delta^{jl}\delta^{kn}
    + \delta^{im}\delta^{jn}\delta^{kl}\\
    +&  \delta^{in}\delta^{ jk}\delta^{lm} + \delta^{in}\delta^{jl}\delta^{km}
    + \delta^{in}\delta^{jm}\delta^{ kl}
    \Big)
\end{align}
My current guess is $\beta_l = \frac{4\pi 2^l l!}{(2l+1)!} = \frac{4\pi}{(2l+1)!!} = 4\pi \cdot\left(\frac{{}_{2l+2}P_{l+1}}{2^{l+1}}\right)^{-1}$ which fits the sequence $1,3,15,105$  [(source)](https://oeis.org/search?q=1+3+15+105&language=english&go=Search) and has a combinatorial origin.

To clarify the identity, the integral is over the (two dimensional) surface
of a unit three dimensional sphere. $\hat{r}^{i_j}$ is a unit vector with three components.
Lastly the $\delta^{i_mi_n} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }i_m=i_n\\ 0 &\text{if } i_m\neq i_n\end{cases}$.

The method I used to calculate the $l=0,1,2,3$ terms was by contracting the index pairs $(i_1,i_2)(i_3,i_4)...(i_{2l-1},i_{2l})$ on both sides ([inspired by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423657/an-integral-about-unit-vector-over-the-whole-space-int-n-in-jn-ln-m-mathrmd)). This leads the left-hand side to become,
$$\oint_{r=1} (\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}})^l d\Omega= 
\oint_{r=1} 1 d\Omega = 4\pi $$
Which is true for all $l\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. Contracting the right-hand side is however more difficult. This I did with pen and paper up to $l=3$. Each element of the sum on the right-hand side after contracted will become either $3, 3^2, \cdots $ or $3^l $.  Currently I have not found a way to do this for general $l$. I have looked at an [other method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409144/integrating-unit-vectors-on-the-surface-of-the-unit-sphere%20), however was not successful.

Thanks!

Comment: I recently need this identity and I also get the factor $\frac{4\pi}{(2\ell+1)!!}$.
What I do is evaluate the integral
$${\small \int \frac{d\Omega_{\hat{r}}}{4\pi}\prod_{k=1}^{2\ell}(\hat{r}\cdot \hat{r}_k)}
= \left. {\small \prod_k \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_k}
\int \frac{d\Omega_{\hat{r}}}{4\pi} e^{\hat{r} \cdot (\sum_k \eta_k \hat{r}_k)}}\right|_{\eta=0}
= \left. {\small \prod_k\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_k}\frac{\sinh\left|\sum_k \eta_k \hat{r}_k\right|}{
|\sum_k \eta_k \hat{r}_k|}}\right|_{\eta=0}$$
and extract the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I agree that $$\int \frac{d\Omega_{\hat{r}}}{4\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{2l}\hat{r}\cdot \hat{r}_k = \prod_{k=1}^{2l} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_k} \frac{\sinh|\sum_{m=1}^{2l}\eta_m\hat{r}_m|}{|\sum_{m=1}^{2l}\eta_m\hat{r}_m|} \Big|_{\eta = 0 }$$. I tried calculating the derivative and product on the right-hand side and got a $0/0 $ limit. After applying l'Hopitals rule I still was still unable to remove the divergences. How did you extract the coefficients?

Comment: You don't apply l'Hopitals rule. Taylor expand RHS and use the fact only  the term $\frac{|\sum_{m=1}^{2l}\eta_m\hat{r}_m|^{2l}}{(2l+1)!}$ contains monomials of correct exponents to contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d\Omega_{u}$ be standard measure for $u \in S^2$.

For $v_1,\ldots, v_{2\ell} \in S^{2}$, consider following angular average over $u$:

$$\mathcal{E} \stackrel{def}{=} \verb/E/_{u}\left[ \prod\limits_{k=1}^{2\ell} (u\cdot v_k) \right]
= \int \frac{d\Omega_u}{4\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{2\ell} (u\cdot v_k)
$$
Introduce auxiliary variables $\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_{2\ell}$, we can rewrite RHS as derivative of a function
at all $\eta_k = 0$.
$$\mathcal{E} = 
\left.{\small \left(\prod_{k=1}^{2\ell}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_k}\right) 
\int \frac{d\Omega_u}{4\pi}
e^{u\cdot(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2\ell}\eta_k v_k)}
}\right|_{\eta=0}
=
\left.{\small \left(\prod_{k=1}^{2\ell}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_k}\right) 
\frac{\sinh\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2\ell}\eta_k v_k\right|}
{\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2\ell}\eta_k v_k\right|}}\right|_{\eta=0}
$$
To compute the derivative, Taylor expand rightmost function and look for coefficients in front on the monomial $\eta_1\ldots\eta_{2\ell}$.

It is clear the only term contribute is
$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2\ell}\eta_k v_k\right|^{2\ell}}
{(2\ell+1)!}
=
\frac{\left(
\color{red}{\cancelto{\rlap{\text{ doesn't contribute}}
}{\color{gray}{
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2\ell}\eta_k^2
}}}
+ 2\sum\limits_{1\le i < j \le 2\ell} \eta_i\eta_j (v_i\cdot v_j)\right)^\ell}
{(2\ell+1)!}\tag{*1}
$$
To get an $\eta_1\ldots\eta_{2\ell}$ from above, we take a $\eta_{i_k}\eta_{j_k}$ from $k^{th}$ factor for $k = 1,\ldots, \ell$ subject to the constraint
that all pairs $(i_k,j_k)$ are disjoint.
This is equivalent to demand the pairs $(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),\ldots$ form a partition of the symbols $\{ 1,\ldots,2\ell \}$.

For any pair $p = \{a, b\}$, let $i_p = \min(a,b)$ and
$j_p = \max(a,b)$.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of partitions of symbols $\{ 1, \ldots, 2\ell \}$ into $\ell$ pairs.

For any $P = \{ p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_\ell\} \in \mathcal{P}$, we will order its element so that $ i_{p_1} < i_{p_2} < \cdots < i_{p_\ell}$. The coefficient we want now has the form

$$\frac{2^\ell}{(2\ell+1)!}\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}}
({\rm coeff ?})\prod_{p\in P} \left(v_{i_{p}}\cdot v_{j_{p}}\right)$$

The only piece that is missing are the values of the coefficients.

For any partition $P$, there are $\ell$ factors in RHS($*1$) one can pickup a pair $p_1$. Once source of $p_1$ is fixed, there remains $\ell-1$ factors in RHS($*1$) one can pickup the pair $p_2$. Repeat this argument for remaining pairs, we find the missing coefficients are all $\ell!$.

The end result is
$$\mathcal{E} 
= \frac{2^\ell\ell!}{(2\ell+1)!}
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}} 
\prod_{p\in P} \left(v_{i_p}\cdot v_{j_p}\right)
= \frac{1}{(2\ell+1)!!}
\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}}
\prod_{p\in P} \left(v_{i_p}\cdot v_{j_p}\right)
$$

Replace $v_k$ by the basis unit vectors $\hat{e}_{\alpha_k}$ and notice $\hat{e}_\alpha \cdot \hat{e}_\beta = \delta^{\alpha\beta}$, we get

$$\int d\Omega_\hat{r} \prod_{k=1}^{2\ell} \hat{r}^{\alpha_i}
=
\int d\Omega_\hat{r} \prod_{k=1}^{2\ell}(\hat{r}\cdot \hat{e}_{\alpha_i})
= \frac{4\pi}{(2\ell+1)!!}
\sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}}\prod_{p\in P}\delta^{\alpha_{i_p}\alpha_{j_p}}
$$

The coefficient you want is indeed what you have guessed: $\frac{4\pi}{(2\ell+1)!!}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is indeed the correct way to find the coefficient.